# Reading data in from file

Tags: c#, file, text

Here is link if you want to download application:

[Simple banking app](http://www.mediafire.com/?054s4a7fsanq7q5)

[Text file with data to read](http://www.mediafire.com/?azsav2asmazvfpp)

I am trying to create a simple banking application that reads in data from a text file. So far i have managed to read in all the customers which there are 20 of them. However when reading in the accounts and transactions stuff it only reads in 20 but there is alot more in the text file.

Here is what i have so far. I think it has something to do with the nested for loop in the getNextCustomer method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace e_SOFT_Banking
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static ArrayList bankDetails = new ArrayList();
        public static ArrayList accDetails = new ArrayList();
        public static ArrayList tranDetails = new ArrayList();

        string inputDataFile = @"C:\e-SOFT_v1.txt";

        const int numCustItems = 14;
        const int numAccItems = 7;
        const int numTransItems = 5;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            setUpBank();
        }

        private void btnShowData_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            showListsOfCust();
        }

        private void setUpBank()
        {
            readData();
        }

        private void showListsOfCust()
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();

            foreach (Customer c in bankDetails)
                listBox1.Items.Add(c.getCustomerNumber() + " " + c.getCustomerTitle() + " " + c.getFirstName()
                                   + " " + c.getInitials() + " " + c.getSurname() + " " + c.getDateOfBirth()
                                   + " " + c.getHouseNameNumber() + " " + c.getStreetName() + " " + c.getArea()
                                   + " " + c.getCityTown() + " " + c.getCounty() + " " + c.getPostcode()
                                   + " " + c.getPassword() + " " + c.getNumberAccounts());

            foreach (Account a in accDetails)
                listBox1.Items.Add(a.getAccSort() + " " + a.getAccNumber() + " " + a.getAccNick() + " " + a.getAccDate()
                                   + " " + a.getAccCurBal() + " " + a.getAccOverDraft() + " " + a.getAccNumTrans());

            foreach (Transaction t in tranDetails)
                listBox1.Items.Add(t.getDate() + " " + t.getType() + " " + t.getDescription() + " " + t.getAmount()
                                   + " " + t.getBalAfter());
        }

        private void readData()
        {
            StreamReader readerIn = null;
            Transaction curTrans;
            Account curAcc;
            Customer curCust;
            bool anyMoreData;
            string[] customerData = new string[numCustItems];
            string[] accountData = new string[numAccItems];
            string[] transactionData = new string[numTransItems];

            if (readOK(inputDataFile, ref readerIn))
            {
                anyMoreData = getNextCustomer(readerIn, customerData, accountData, transactionData);

                while (anyMoreData == true)
                {
                    curCust = new Customer(customerData[0], customerData[1], customerData[2], customerData[3], customerData[4],
                                           customerData[5], customerData[6], customerData[7], customerData[8], customerData[9],
                                           customerData[10], customerData[11], customerData[12], customerData[13]);

                    curAcc = new Account(accountData[0], accountData[1], accountData[2], accountData[3], accountData[4],
                                         accountData[5], accountData[6]);

                    curTrans = new Transaction(transactionData[0], transactionData[1], transactionData[2], transactionData[3], 
                                               transactionData[4]);

                    bankDetails.Add(curCust);
                    accDetails.Add(curAcc);
                    tranDetails.Add(curTrans);

                    anyMoreData = getNextCustomer(readerIn, customerData, accountData, transactionData);
                }

                if (readerIn != null)
                    readerIn.Close();
            }
        }

        private bool getNextCustomer(StreamReader inNext, string[] nextCustomerData, string[] nextAccountData, string[] nextTransactionData)
        {
            string nextLine;
            int numCItems = nextCustomerData.Count();
            int numAItems = nextAccountData.Count();
            int numTItems = nextTransactionData.Count();

            for (int i = 0; i < numCItems; i++)
            {
                nextLine = inNext.ReadLine();
                if (nextLine != null)
                {
                    nextCustomerData[i] = nextLine;
                    if (i == 13)
                    {
                        int cItems = Convert.ToInt32(nextCustomerData[13]);
                        for (int q = 0; q < cItems; q++)
                        {
                            for (int a = 0; a < numAItems; a++)
                            {
                                nextLine = inNext.ReadLine();
                                nextAccountData[a] = nextLine;
                                if (a == 6)
                                {
                                    int aItems = Convert.ToInt32(nextAccountData[6]);
                                    for (int w = 0; w < aItems; w++)
                                    {
                                        for (int t = 0; t < numTItems; t++)
                                        {
                                            nextLine = inNext.ReadLine();
                                            nextTransactionData[t] = nextLine;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        private bool readOK(string readFile, ref StreamReader readerIn)
        {
            try
            {
                readerIn = new StreamReader(readFile);
                return true;
            }

            catch (FileNotFoundException notFound)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR Opening file (when reading data in)" + " - File could not be found.\n" + notFound.Message);
                return false;
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR Opening File (when reading data in)" + "- Operation failed.\n" + e.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also have three classes one for customers, one for accounts and one for transactions, which follow in that order.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace e_SOFT_Banking
{
    class Customer
    {
        private string customerNumber;
        private string customerTitle;
        private string firstName;
        private string initials;  //not required - defaults to null
        private string surname;
        private string dateOfBirth;
        private string houseNameNumber;
        private string streetName;
        private string area; //not required - defaults to null
        private string cityTown;
        private string county;
        private string postcode;
        private string password;
        private int numberAccounts;

        public Customer(string theCustomerNumber, string theCustomerTitle, string theFirstName, string theInitials, string theSurname, string theDateOfBirth, string theHouseNameNumber, string theStreetName, string theArea, string theCityTown, string theCounty, string thePostcode, string thePassword, string theNumberAccounts)
        {
            customerNumber = theCustomerNumber;
            customerTitle = theCustomerTitle;
            firstName = theFirstName;
            initials = theInitials;
            surname = theSurname;
            dateOfBirth = theDateOfBirth;
            houseNameNumber = theHouseNameNumber;
            streetName = theStreetName;
            area = theArea;
            cityTown = theCityTown;
            county = theCounty;
            postcode = thePostcode;
            password = thePassword;
            setNumberAccounts(theNumberAccounts);

        }

        public string getCustomerNumber()
        {
            return customerNumber;
        }

        public string getCustomerTitle()
        {
            return customerTitle;
        }

        public string getFirstName()
        {
            return firstName;
        }

        public string getInitials()
        {
            return initials;
        }

        public string getSurname()
        {
            return surname;
        }

        public string getDateOfBirth()
        {
            return dateOfBirth;
        }

        public string getHouseNameNumber()
        {
            return houseNameNumber;
        }

        public string getStreetName()
        {
            return streetName;
        }

        public string getArea()
        {
            return area;
        }

        public string getCityTown()
        {
            return cityTown;
        }

        public string getCounty()
        {
            return county;
        }

        public string getPostcode()
        {
            return postcode;
        }

        public string getPassword()
        {
            return password;
        }

        public int getNumberAccounts()
        {
            return numberAccounts;
        }


        public void setCustomerNumber(string inCustomerNumber)
        {
            customerNumber = inCustomerNumber;
        }

        public void setCustomerTitle(string inCustomerTitle)
        {
            customerTitle = inCustomerTitle;
        }

        public void setFirstName(string inFirstName)
        {
            firstName = inFirstName;
        }

        public void setInitials(string inInitials)
        {
            initials = inInitials;
        }

        public void setSurname(string inSurname)
        {
            surname = inSurname;
        }

        public void setDateOfBirth(string inDateOfBirth)
        {
            dateOfBirth = inDateOfBirth;
        }

        public void setHouseNameNumber(string inHouseNameNumber)
        {
            houseNameNumber = inHouseNameNumber;
        }

        public void setStreetName(string inStreetName)
        {
            streetName = inStreetName;
        }

        public void setArea(string inArea)
        {
            area = inArea;
        }

        public void setCityTown(string inCityTown)
        {
            cityTown = inCityTown;
        }

        public void setCounty(string inCounty)
        {
            county = inCounty;
        }

        public void setPostcode(string inPostcode)
        {
            postcode = inPostcode;
        }

        public void setPassword(string inPassword)
        {
            password = inPassword;
        }

        public void setNumberAccounts(string inNumberAccounts)
        {
            try
            {
                numberAccounts = Convert.ToInt32(inNumberAccounts);
            }
            catch (FormatException invalidInput)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("ERROR" + invalidInput.Message + "Please enter a valid number");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Accounts:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace e_SOFT_Banking
{
    class Account
    {
        private string accSort;
        private Int64 accNumber;
        private string accNick;
        private string accDate;  //not required - defaults to null
        private double accCurBal;
        private double accOverDraft;
        private int accNumTrans;

        public Account(string theAccSort, string theAccNumber, string theAccNick, 
                       string theAccDate, string theAccCurBal, string theAccOverDraft, 
                       string theAccNumTrans)
        {
            accSort = theAccSort;
            setAccNumber(theAccNumber);
            accNick = theAccNick;
            accDate = theAccDate;
            setAccCurBal(theAccCurBal);
            setAccOverDraft(theAccOverDraft);
            setAccNumTrans(theAccNumTrans);
        }

        public string getAccSort()
        {
            return accSort;
        }

        public long getAccNumber()
        {
            return accNumber;
        }

        public string getAccNick()
        {
            return accNick;
        }

        public string getAccDate()
        {
            return accDate;
        }

        public double getAccCurBal()
        {
            return accCurBal;
        }

        public double getAccOverDraft()
        {
            return accOverDraft;
        }

        public int getAccNumTrans()
        {
            return accNumTrans;
        }


        public void setAccSort(string inAccSort)
        {
            accSort = inAccSort;
        }

        public void setAccNumber(string inAccNumber)
        {
            try
            {
                accNumber = Convert.ToInt64(inAccNumber);
            }
            catch (FormatException invalidInput)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("ERROR" + invalidInput.Message + "Please enter a valid number");
            }
        }

        public void setAccNick(string inAccNick)
        {
            accNick = inAccNick;
        }

        public void setAccDate(string inAccDate)
        {
            accDate = inAccDate;
        }

        public void setAccCurBal(string inAccCurBal)
        {
            try
            {
                accCurBal = Convert.ToDouble(inAccCurBal);
            }
            catch (FormatException invalidInput)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("ERROR" + invalidInput.Message + "Please enter a valid number");
            }
        }

        public void setAccOverDraft(string inAccOverDraft)
        {
            try
            {
                accOverDraft = Convert.ToDouble(inAccOverDraft);
            }
            catch (FormatException invalidInput)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("ERROR" + invalidInput.Message + "Please enter a valid number");
            }
        }

        public void setAccNumTrans(string inAccNumTrans)
        {
            try
            {
                accNumTrans = Convert.ToInt32(inAccNumTrans);
            }
            catch (FormatException invalidInput)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("ERROR" + invalidInput.Message + "Please enter a valid number");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Transactions:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace e_SOFT_Banking
{
    class Transaction
    {
        private string date;
        private string type;
        private string description;
        private double amount;  //not required - defaults to null
        private double balAfter;


        public Transaction(string theDate, string theType, string theDescription,
                       string theAmount, string theBalAfter)
        {
            date = theDate;
            type = theType;
            description = theDescription;
            setAmount(theAmount);
            setBalAfter(theBalAfter);
        }

        public string getDate()
        {
            return date;
        }

        public string getType()
        {
            return type;
        }

        public string getDescription()
        {
            return description;
        }

        public double getAmount()
        {
            return amount;
        }

        public double getBalAfter()
        {
            return balAfter;
        }

        public void setDate(string inDate)
        {
            date = inDate;
        }

        public void setType(string inType)
        {
            type = inType;
        }

        public void setDescription(string inDescription)
        {
            description = inDescription;
        }

        public void setAmount(string inAmount)
        {
            try
            {
                amount = Convert.ToDouble(inAmount);
            }
            catch (FormatException invalidInput)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("ERROR" + invalidInput.Message + "Please enter a valid number");
            }
        }

        public void setBalAfter(string inBalAfter)
        {
            try
            {
                balAfter = Convert.ToDouble(inBalAfter);
            }
            catch (FormatException invalidInput)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("ERROR" + invalidInput.Message + "Please enter a valid number");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Questions: 
Can the structure of the file be changed or do you have to live with it as is?
Do you know how to use regular expressions?
How many accounts are actually in the text file? What is the record delimiter?

Comment: No, unfortunatly the file structure can not be changed. No i dont know how to use a regular expression. The amount of accounts and customers and transactions is all unknown and should be different. As for the delimeter it is a line by line.

Comment: As far as I can tell the application is working properlly. 60 lines will be output to the list box one per customer. Is this not what is expected?

Comment: Well, i know it partly works because there are 20 Customers, however it is only doing 20 accounts and trasactions. There are however quite a few more than that. From what i can see after looking at the ouput it is gathering all of the customers, but only the last 20 accounts and transactions from the text file.

Comment: debug it an see how many records are in nextCustomerData.Count() The problem might not be with the loop itself it might not getting the hole number of customers. Or  open the text file and look at the 20 entry see what's diffrent about it it might be a character mismatch

Comment: Dude, I can't figure this out. It appears to work but... Usually when I encounter this type of problem; I rewrite the code (keep this version though) walking myself through the process to ensure that I'm not missing something. Good luck.

Comment: Just curious, is there any reason you do `getAccOverDraft` and `setAccOverDraft`. Instead of one property method `AccOverDraft` with getters/setters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem start with the following

```
string[] customerData = new string[numCustItems];
string[] accountData = new string[numAccItems];
string[] transactionData = new string[numTransItems];
```

With this structure and the call

```
anyMoreData = getNextCustomer(readerIn, customerData, accountData, transactionData);
```

you will get only one accountData and one transactionData for one customer.

Please redesign your code, so that your data objects know how to read theirselve from the datastream.